# Odoo 10 Custom Qweb report : Error to render compiling AST TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: report, odoo-10, qweb

I'm trying to extended an existing report from a vendor module, inserting the amount converted to text, so I started from scratch creating the module for my report:

This is my report_file.py

```
from openerp import api, models
from num2words import num2words

class ReportReceiptReprint(models.AbstractModel):
    _name = 'report.aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint'

@api.multi
def _numwords(val):
    pretext = val
    text = ''
    entire_part = int((str(pretext).split('.'))[0])
    decimal_part = int((str(pretext).split('.'))[1])  
    text+=num2words(entire_part, lang='es').upper()
    text+=' CON '
    text+=num2words(decimal_part, lang='es').upper()
    if decimal_num > 1:
        text+= ' CENTAVOS '
    else:
        text+= ' CENTAVO '
    return text

@api.multi
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    report = self.env['report']._get_report_from_name('aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint')
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': docids,
        'doc_model': report.model,
        'docs': self,
        'num_words': _numwords,
        }
    return self.env['report'].render('aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint', docargs)
```

And my report_file.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<data>
   <template id="report_receipt_reprint_inherit" inherit_id="aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint">
     <xpath expr="//div[@class='numbers_text']" position="replace">
        <div style="font-size: 14px; width: 100%">
          <b>Son: <span t-esc="num_words(receipt.amount_total)"/></b>
        </div>
     </xpath>
   </template>
</data>
</odoo>
```

but I just get this:

```
Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
Template: 1130
Path: /templates/t/t/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/b/span
Node: <span t-esc="num_words(receipt.amount_total)"/>
```

This happen even if I put the function _numwords() into the models.py file of the main module.
The extend for the module works if I avoid to call the function, the text is inserted as expected. num2words is installed.

I'll appreciate any comment or suggestion!
Thanks in advance.

**==EDIT==**

report_file.py

```
from odoo import api, models
from num2words import num2words


class ReportReceiptReprint(models.AbstractModel):
      _name = 'report.aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint'

@api.multi
def _numwords(self, val):
    pretext = float(val)
    text = ''
    entire_part = int((str(pretext).split('.'))[0])
    decimal_part = (pretext-float(entire_part))*100
    decimal_part = int((str(decimal_part).split('.'))[0])
    text += num2words(entire_part, lang='es').upper()
    text += ' LEMPIRAS CON '
    text += num2words(decimal_part, lang='es').upper()
    if decimal_part > 1:
        text += ' CENTAVOS '
    else:
        text += ' CENTAVO '
    return text

@api.multi
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
    # report = self.env['report']._get_report_from_name('aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint')
    docargs = {
        'doc_ids': docids,
        'doc_model': self.env.context.get('active_model'),
        'docs': self.env['pos.order'].browse(int(docids)),
        'num_words': self._numbwords,
    }
    return self.env['report'].render('aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint', docargs)
```

I don't know why the commented line "# report =" was causing a lot of problems.

Comment: Maybe self.numwords also try with braces and param

Comment: I appreciate your comment @MuhammadYusuf , but I changed the code like this:
` 'num_words': self._numwords(val), ` but still getting the same message.

Answer (score 0):

On your python file just change the function calling to,

**'num_words': self._numwords(data['form']['amount_total']),** &
**def _numwords(self, val)**

Where make sure to check that your passed value of **amount_total** gets from your data and that value you have to pass on the _numwords function.
And on the XML file  **t-esc="num_words"** try to access the value like this.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks @DipenShah but the value is not returned, the report is displayed but without the expected value.

Comment: Hello, @RauLeo88 You want to convert the amount_total into text right? then on your code, you are returning the text where your amount_total(10) return with (TEN).So when you check my explanation previously and try to print according to what data you get?

Comment: Hi @Dipen-Shah, yes I expect to get the word instead of the number but after your code I just get white space after the 'Son:' label, the ** t-esc="num_words" ** returns nothing.

Comment: Hello, @RauLeo88 Okay can you check data['form']['amount_total'] what you get while printing this. And can you also trace with the def _numwords  function what they return?

Comment: Hi, @Dipen-Shah, the trace for the function returns the value expected ( text ),  _numwords(123.25)
'CIENTO VEINTITRÉS CON VEINTICINCO CENTAVOS ',
But printing the form value returns this:
Error to render compiling AST
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
Template: 1130
Path: /templates/t/t/div[2]/div[9]/div[1]/b/span
Node: <span t-esc="['form']['amount_total']"/>

Comment: Hi, @Dipen-Shah, I noted that try to calling num2words directly returns the same error 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable', i don't know if there a problem with this tool.

Comment: Hello @RauLeo88, I think you didn't check my solution and not to apply exactly. first thing on def render_html() function change the line 'num_words': self._numwords(data['form']['amount_total']) where first check the what value you have.2nd thing changes this function declaration & def _numwords(self, val)  where check what data return in which type. then if all data is printing well according to your req then on the XML <span t-esc="num_words"/> just try to print.

Comment: Hello @Dipen-Shah, thanks a lot for the help, lately I figure out how to make the report work but with the change in the function data['form'] generated a Key error. I changed the definition of the function to include self and changed the render_html definition too in my edit you can see the changes.

Comment: @RauLeo88 If you just search on Odoo with "render_html" function then there you got the idea about the report working structure and how to access the value from the data. Just try to trace the whole code what you get and where you stuck.

Comment: @RauLeo88 If you just search on Odoo with "render_html" function then there you got the idea about the report working structure and how to access the value from the data. Just try to trace the whole code what you get and where you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
@api.milti
def _numbwords(self, val)....

@api.multi
def render_html(self, docids, data=None):
# report = self.env['report']._get_report_from_name('aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint')
# This line caused problems so commented out
docargs = {
    'doc_ids': docids,
    'doc_model': self.env.context.get('active_model'),
    'docs': self.env['pos.order'].browse(int(docids)), # have to include the model and methods to index the documents
    'num_words': self._numbwords,
}
return self.env['report'].render('aces_pos_reorder.receipt_reprint', docargs)
```

That's all